# WordPress theme activation hook in php class

Tags: php, wordpress, class

I want to run a function when my theme is activated. I have to add the theme activation hook within a php class:

```
final class My_Class_Name {

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (self::$instance == null) {
            self::$instance = new self;               
            self::$instance->actions();
        } else {
            throw new BadFunctionCallException(sprintf('Plugin %s already instantiated', __CLASS__));
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }


   // some code

   add_action('after_switch_theme', array( $this, 'activate' ));

   function activate() {
      // some code
   }

   // more code

}

My_Class_Name::getInstance();
```

When I activate my theme I get the following php error:

> PHP Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, class 'My_Class_Name' does not have a method
>   'activate' in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-themes/test/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php
>   on line 288

If I use `add_action('after_switch_theme', 'activate' );`

I get

> PHP Fatal error: Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active

How can I make the hook work?

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple way i made it work.

```
final class My_Class_Name {

    // some code

    public function __construct(){
        add_action('after_switch_theme', array( $this, 'activate' ));
    }

    public function activate() {
        file_put_contents(__DIR__.'\de.log','TEST');
    }

    // more code

}

new My_Class_Name();
```

Here is another way you can instantiate.

```
class My_Class_Name{

    protected static $instance = null;

    public function __construct(){}

    public static function get_instance() {
        // If the single instance hasn't been set, set it now.
        if ( null == self::$instance ) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
}

My_Class_Name::get_instance();
```

Comment: Instantiating the class gives a fatal error. I think because i am using self instance. I have updated my code.

Comment: @CyberJunkie updated with another way you can instantiate your class :)